# У меня ещё таки / ещё-таки есть один вопрос

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> У меня ещё таки / ещё-таки есть один вопрос.

> Я ещё таки / ещё-таки этого не сделал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ещë* — наречие. А с наречиями частица ТАКИ пишется через дефис. Значит, пишем через дефис:

*У меня **ещё-таки** есть один вопрос*;

*Я **ещё-таки** этого не сделал*.